# Overlaying p5.js content over html

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

Hi all I'm relatively new to p5.js and i have challenged myself to make a page where a video is played in the background while p5.js components (for example rectangles) can freely move over the playback.
I wanted to ask since I can't find a solution is there a chance this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out minutes after, you need to create a video component and then you need to store that component in an image component and then you can layer it with the other components on the screen.